# Suggestion for software to control internet

Tags: internet

I need to implement a gateway that will allow me to control the access to the internet  of a network made up of a about half a dozen of workstations. My main obejectives are the following:

1- Monitoring of traffic
2- Logging of traffic
3- Access control - block websites (mainly adult) and certian traffic(example torrents)
4- Possibly cache content
5- Easy management interface
6- Preferable free and opensource

Serverfault users can you please suggest from your vast experience which software you think is the best to suit my needs?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClearOS is your answer. (www.clearfoundation.com)

set up and execution could hardly be simpler. It's free and super solid.

also has a GUI and a webbrowser interface for those that dont like to get messy.

Comment: I like it! look very pro.

Answer (score 2):

All of your requirements (with the possible exception of #5) can be handled with Squid caching proxy and DansGuardian.  There are probably products (both free and commercial) out there that combine them into a cohesive platform.

Comment: There is dansguardian webmin module that makes management very easy

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dgwebminmodule/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/), it has nice easy reporting and acts along the lines of an appliances so is reasonably easy to administer. The majority of the modules seem to be free and it has both online and emailed reports with a nice break down of where traffic went.

You can also either log or block websites and protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to:

http://www.endian.com

http://www.smoothwall.org

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at using OpenDNS for your internet DNS lookups.  You can setup rules for what people can and can not have access to, monitor what people are looking at, see reports of unacceptable access attempts and better still it's free to use.

The paid version lets you have even more control, but I've found the free version does pretty much everything I need.